# When I click edit, only top row shows

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller

In the second foreach loop I have a dropdown list I want to display when I press the edit button. I want to display the dropdown list for which row I want to edit, right now it displays the top row matter the edit button I click. I guess I need to clarify each foreach value with an Id and connect each edit button with that id, but I don't know how. any help is appreciated.

index.cshtml

```
<table id="tblCustomers" class="table table-striped">
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model.Organisations)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span>@item.HsaId</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span>@item.OrgsName</span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="PartnerOrg">
                        <span>@item.PartnersLgId</span>
                        <div id="lgpartners">
                            <select multiple="multiple">
                                @foreach (var p in Model.Partners)
                                {
                                    <option>@p.LgId</option>
                                }
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a id="Edit" onclick="becomevisible()">Edit</a>
                        <a id="Update" style="display:none">Update</a>
                        <a id="Cancel" style="display:none" onclick="becomehidden()">Cancel</a>
                        <a id="Delete">Delete</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

javascript.js

```
function becomevisible() {
    document.getElementById("lgpartners").style.display = "block";
}

function becomehidden() {
    document.getElementById("lgpartners").style.display = "none";
}
```

I have searched on Google and tried finding the answer to my question but haven't found one I liked yet

Comment: IDs need to be UNIQUE. Also this is not a C# question. Please click [edit], then the `[<>]` snippet editor and paste relevant RENDERED HTML, CSS, Script and frameworks used

Comment: In your first for each loop, get index along with value, and append that index to lgpartners. For e.g, your div's ids would be like lgpartners0, lgpartners1. Then in your becomevisible pass that index. You have to figure out the full code by yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDs need to be UNIQUE

You really need to delegate.

Also IF you use `A` as a button, add a href to get the pointer cursor

Note I use hidden instead of display:none and changed all IDs to class

You can toggle a class that contains display: hidden/block instead

If you want to delete the row, you just need

```
if (tgt.matches(".Delete")) {
  parent.remove();
}
```

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  document.getElementById("tblCustomers").addEventListener("click", e => {
    const tgt = e.target;
    const parent = tgt.closest("tr");
    if (tgt.matches(".Edit")) {
      parent.querySelector(".lgpartners").hidden = false;
      parent.querySelector(".Cancel").hidden = false;
    }
    else if (tgt.matches(".Cancel")) {
      tgt.hidden = true;
      parent.querySelector(".lgpartners").hidden = true;
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<table id="tblCustomers" class="table table-striped">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span>@item.HsaId</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span>@item.OrgsName</span>
      </td>
      <td class="PartnerOrg">
        <span>@item.PartnersLgId</span>
        <div class="lgpartners" hidden>
          <select multiple="multiple">
            <option>@p.LgId</option>
            <option>@p.LgId</option>
            <option>@p.LgId</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="#" class="Edit">Edit</a>
        <a href="#" class="Update" hidden>Update</a>
        <a href="#" class="Cancel" hidden>Cancel</a>
        <a href="#" class="Delete">Delete</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span>@item.HsaId</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span>@item.OrgsName</span>
      </td>
      <td class="PartnerOrg">
        <span>@item.PartnersLgId</span>
        <div class="lgpartners" hidden>
          <select multiple="multiple">
            <option>@p.LgId</option>
            <option>@p.LgId</option>
            <option>@p.LgId</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="#" class="Edit">Edit</a>
        <a href="#" class="Update" hidden>Update</a>
        <a href="#" class="Cancel" hidden>Cancel</a>
        <a href="#" class="Delete">Delete</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because you're repeating the same `id` in the content you create in the loop. This is causing duplicate `id` attributes in the DOM, which is invalid. They must be unique.

To fix this, use `class` attributes on the repeated elements instead. You will also need to amend your JS logic to traverse the DOM to find content related to the client element instead of selecting it directly.

Below is a working example of how to do this. Note the use of `addEventListener()` instead of inline event handlers. The latter are no longer good practice and should be avoided where possible.

Also note that I used a class on the `tr` to control the visibility of the relevant buttons in CSS.

```js
document.querySelector('#tblCustomers').addEventListener('click', e => {
  const tr = e.target.closest('tr');
  
  if (e.target.matches('.edit'))  
    editRow(tr);
    
  if (e.target.matches('.cancel'))  
    cancelEditRow(tr);
});

const editRow = tr => tr.classList.add('editing');
const cancelEditRow = tr => tr.classList.remove('editing');
```

```css
tr .lgpartners,
tr .update,
tr .cancel {
  display: none;
}

tr.editing .lgpartners,
tr.editing .update,
tr.editing .cancel {
  display: inline;
}
tr.editing .edit,
tr.editing .delete {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table id="tblCustomers" class="table table-striped">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span>@item.HsaId</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span>@item.OrgsName</span>
      </td>
      <td class="partnerOrg">
        <span>@item.PartnersLgId</span>
        <div class="lgpartners">
          <select multiple="multiple">
            <option>@p.LgId</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a class="edit">Edit</a>
        <a class="update">Update</a>
        <a class="cancel">Cancel</a>
        <a class="delete">Delete</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span>@item.HsaId</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span>@item.OrgsName</span>
      </td>
      <td class="partnerOrg">
        <span>@item.PartnersLgId</span>
        <div class="lgpartners">
          <select multiple="multiple">
            <option>@p.LgId</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a class="edit">Edit</a>
        <a class="update">Update</a>
        <a class="cancel">Cancel</a>
        <a class="delete">Delete</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```